How to Retrieve Sales Channel Details (Origin, Referrer, Landing Page) for Orders via Magento API?
I am importing orders from a client's Adobe Commerce (Magento) store using the API. I need to retrieve sales channel details for orders, specifically the following information:

The origin of the order (e.g., UTM source or medium, such as Google or Bing)
The referring site (e.g., the HTTP referrer)
The landing page where the customer started their session

What I've tried:
I explored the GET /rest/V1/orders and GET /rest/V1/products/{id} endpoints of the Magento REST API but couldn’t find explicit fields for this data. I reviewed the API responses but couldn’t locate any information related to the order sales channel.
How can I retrieve this sales channel information using the Magento REST API or any other API method?
Any guidance, examples, or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Based on your question, it seems you were attempting to fetch the order details from Adobe Commerce. To proceed, ensure that the required details are visible in the order information within the Adobe Commerce admin panel or confirm if the data is being stored on the Adobe Commerce side. If the necessary data is present in the Admin panel, you can extend the Adobe Commerce API to include additional fields for the required data.
Typically, this type of data is managed by third-party analytics or marketing tools, such as Google Analytics, Adobe Analytics, or extensions that integrate with Magento for campaign tracking.
